# Select element whose child/grandchildren/.. contains an element with a specified pattern

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml

I am using `lxml`, using the `html` module of the library.

How can I get the element that contains an element with certain characteristics?

For example:

```
<TR>
  <TD>Welcome</TD>
  <TD>other</TD>
</TR>
<TR>
  <TD>Bye Bye</TD>
  <TD>another</TD>
</TR>
```

How can I select the `<TR>` element which contains the `<TD>Welcome</TD>`?
Not sure how to write down the proper `xpath` pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use XPath, this ought to work:

```
e = doc.xpath('//tr[td[text()="Welcome"]]')[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this.  I am not super skilled with xPath so I would do this

```
myTree = html.fromstring(open(somePath to my htmlfile).read())
rows = [ e for e in myTree if e.tag == 'tr']
for row in rows:
    cells = [e for e in row if e.tag == 'td']
    for cell in cells:
        if cell.text_content = 'Welcome'
        print ' I have the row I want'
        break
```

When the program breaks the row  you will have the first row in the rows that has a cell with the word Welcome.  You can modify this quite a bit.  That is if you type row at the cursor then the row element that will be displayed is your particular row